# 301 Redirect to Incorrect URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I inherited a live Wordpress website where 30+ pages were 301 redirected to the home page. Which is... obviously not ideal.

This is an example of what is happening:

https://www.example.com/shop -- 301 --> https://example.com

In that scenario, this is what I want to be happening:

https://www.example.com/shop --> https://www.example.com/shop

I'd consider myself a beginner at Apache. I don't typically use htaccess except for basic SSL redirects. I've been banging my head against the wall all night so any advice is welcome.

EDIT:

Caching doesn't seem to be the issue as the redirect persists in Chrome incognito. Here's my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

UPDATE:

This code in the wp-config file appears to be causing issues. When I comment it out, some of the URLs are no longer 301 but the page content that is loading is still the home page on every page.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

Comment: We cannot help with that little information. We do not know what "the original links" are, nor "where they are supposed to go"...

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I've updated to include a specific example of what is happening. Let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: Hm, so you do _not_ want a redirection to happen at all and you say you disabled the faulty rules, so that you would expect no redirection to happen. Right? To me this looks like you have a simple caching issue. Keep in mind that a 301 is a _permanent_ redirection, so browsers will not fetch the original URL again but follow the previously received redirection until their cache expires. Test yourself using a fresh anonymous browser window. Do you still get wired results or are things fine then?

Comment: You are correct about what I'm trying to do. I just opened in an incognito window and the redirect is still happening. I'll update my questions with my htaccess code just in case I've miscoded something.

Comment: OK, that is valuable information. Next step in debugging is to check what the browser actually receives back. Open the console in your browser (typically F12). In there you will find the "network" tab. Clear it. Then make the request you want to test and check what the browser actually receives back. What do you see?

Comment: It is logging the initial link click as a status 301 which initiates loading the home page next.

Comment: OK, so then your server actually still sends out the 301 redirection. So you did _not_ remove that as you claimed.

Comment: Maybe there is a fallback redirection rule you did not touch? Maybe you modified the wrong distributed configuration file?